# An asymptotic expansion in the form of nested exponents

Tags: notation, asymptotics, definition, exponential-function, fibonacci-numbers

Suppose I have a function $f(x)$ with a linear asymptotic behavior for $x\to\infty$:
$$f(x)=a_0\,x+b_0+o(1).\tag1$$
Suppose, the last term decays roughly exponentially, so if we take its logarithm, we again get a function with a linear asymptotic behavior:
$$\ln(f(x)-(a_0\,x+b_0))=a_1\,x+b_1+o(1),\tag2$$
where $a_1<0$. Repeating the same step again, we get:
$$\ln\!\big(\ln(f(x)-(a_0\,x+b_0))-(a_1\,x+b_1)\big)=a_2\,x+b_2+o(1),\tag3$$
and so on.

So we can write the following asymptotic expansion:
$$\large{f(x) \sim a_0\,x+b_0+e^{a_1 x+b_1+e^{a_{\small 2}x+b_{\small 2}+e^{...}}}}.\tag4$$

Is there a name for such an expansion? Are there any known expansions of this form? When does it converge?

---

The motivation for this question is that the [fibonorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fibonorial.html), that is the product of the Fibonacci numbers
$$n!_F=\prod_{m=1}^n F_m\tag5$$
appears to have a similar asymptotic expansion (although so far I do not have a rigorous proof for that):
$$n!_F \sim c \cdot 5^{-\frac n 2} \, \phi^{\frac{n\,(n+1)}2} e^{-\frac1{\sqrt5} \frac{(-1)^n}{\phi^{2n+1}} \, \Large e^{-\frac12 \frac{(-1)^n}{\phi^{2n+1}} e^{-\frac1{12} \frac{(-1)^n}{\phi^{2n+1}} e^{-\frac{23}{24} \frac{(-1)^n}{\phi^{2n+1}} e^{\frac{24931}{82800} \frac{(-1)^n}{\phi^{2n+1}} e^{^{...}}}}}}}\tag6$$
where 
$$c=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-(-1)^n\phi^{-2n}\right)=\left(-\phi^{-2};\,-\phi^{-2}\right)_\infty\tag7$$ is the [Fibonacci factorial constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciFactorialConstant.html), and the coefficients on the higher levels (replaced above with the ellipsis) are:
$${\small \frac{2869583039}{4128573600},\,\frac{15485246938446577291}{1293723497738290207680},\,\frac{15950805330913927636702617812270117323162487}{1001681391627412794937755717587878089744000},\,...}\tag8$$